# Error (Version not found) when uploading package to Magento Connect

Tags: magento2, module, extensions, magento-connect

I am facing a problem to upload version in magento connect extension. When I am trying to upload the package file for the extension, it's giving the following error.

> An error occurred during upload to channel MagentoConnect: Version not
> found

However I have given the Version Number to 1.0.0.0 and also given the Release Version same in package extension in magento admin. Then the package file is namespace_module-1.0.0.0.tgz. I am trying to upload this file in Upload package section and giving the following error.

May I know what wrong I have done to upload package extension.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Magento connect supports versions split in 4 digits.

You should try setting your version as 1.0.0, repackage then reupload to Magento Connect

Answer (score 1):

It's little late I know. It may help anyone else in here...

Check the 'Stability' value in you package.xml and what you have select during the upload in Magento connect. You may be selecting 'Version Stability' as Stable while in your package it may be something else which would be causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should also make sure that the Magento Extension name is same as the  Extension Key in magento commerce while creating the package.

Your zip should have the name as your extension key, ignore the version number appended to the zip.

**For example :**

Extension Key in magento commerce : **TestingMagento**

So while packaging enter name as : **TestingMagento**

Version Number : **1.0.0.0**

This will create your package extension as **TestingMagento-1.0.0.0.tgz**,  which you want to upload.